# The scrollview doesn't scroll

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I'm trying to use Scrollview but it is not working for me whatsoever.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">
      

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:padding="15dp"
            >
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                .....
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >
                    <TextView
                      ...>

                    </TextView>
                    <ImageView
                       ...>
                    </ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried every solution I found online, but nothing worked.
I tried to add this :
android:orientation="vertical"
to the linearLayout, but it changed nothing. I still can't scroll
How can I get the scrollView to work?

Comment: You probably meant to make the GridLayout's height `wrap_content` (and drop the weight - it's the only item).  You're currently telling the LinearLayout to wrap the GridLayout, but the GridLayout is being told to use the LinearLayout's size, which is a circular dependency.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your layout under the ScrollView Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ScrollActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>
```

Make sure that your Child layout has enough views so that can scrollable.

I hope this can helps you out from your problem ):

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing like this

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).